# I get syntax error, unexpected keyword_end error when deploying on local host using mysql2 db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the following error when deploying it and Im pretty sure there is no syntax error since it runs on a friends machine. Im not sure whats wrong or why i get this error but ive been stuck with this for almost a day. Hence any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Showing /Users/ME/Desktop/MyRailProjects/smyes/app/views/subscribers/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

```
/Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:91: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
/Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:93: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: <%= form_for(@subscriber) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @subscriber.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@subscriber.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscriber from being saved:</h2>
```

Comment: Exact same Ruby/Rails/etc. versions? It could be in a helper, further down in the file, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have **end** keywords, for example:

```
<%= form_for(@subscriber) do |f| %>
  <% if @subscriber.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@subscriber.errors.count, "error") %> ...</h2>
  <% end %> # end for "if @subscriber.errors.any?"
<% end %> # end for "form_for(@subscriber)"
```

Maybe you deployed the source code with mistakes.